# Python Winsound equivalent for Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, audio

I was wondering if there was a winsound equivalent for playing .wav files on Mac?
Preferably a native import.
Thanks

Comment: This should be two questions: (1) reading WAV files, and (2) playing sound. For both problems there are many possibilities in Python and there are many questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: I really just need something for playing .wav files, basically just like how winsound works. I've been switching between a Mac and HP laptop recently because my HP is for school, and I really just want something that works like it. But, sorry if this sounds a bit dumb, but what is the difference between reading WAV files and playing sound?

Comment: They are just two very different tasks. One is about getting the numbers from an audio file into RAM (and probably also the other way round), the other one is about getting numbers from the RAM out through your sound card (and probably also the other way round). There are many ways to do either and there are even more libraries available for Python that do either. It is bad library design to combine both tasks into one library, nevertheless there are also several libraries that do exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native import will cause trouble here, as other modules have said functionality.

I assume you know how to install modules, so I won't go over that.

Here is an option:

1. Pygame (`sudo pip install pygame`)

   ```
   import pygame
   pygame.init()
   pygame.mixer.init()
   sounda= pygame.mixer.Sound("desert_rustle.wav")
   sounda.play()
   ```